# ffmpeg output to multiple rtmp simultaneously

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, stream, video-streaming, audio-streaming

i have this situation:

i need stream to 3 different rtmp

- 1 rtmp is normal all the audio and video
- 2 rtmp is the video but different audio
- 3 rtmp is only audio of first video

this my elaboration...

```
ffmpeg -re -i /usr/VIDEO/my_video.mp4 -i /usr/VIDEO/x_audio.mp3 \
-map 0:v -c:v libx264 -vf format=yuv420p -b:v 2000k -bufsize 3000k -maxrate 2000k -s 1024X576 -g 60 -map 0:a -c:a aac -b:a 192k -ar 44100 -f flv rtmp://my_ip/live/pass \
-map 0:v -c:v libx264 -vf format=yuv420p -b:v 2000k -bufsize 3000k -maxrate 2000k -s 1024X576 -g 60 -map 1:a -streamloop -shortest -f flv rtmp://my_ip/noaudio/pass \
-map 0:a aac -b:a 192k -ar 44100 -f flv rtmp://my_ip/only_audio/pass
```

i was thinking was ok, but is not.

Where I have misstake

Answer (score 1):

Use the [tee muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#tee-1). It's more complicated but more efficient: you can encode streams once and re-use them for multiple outputs.

```
ffmpeg -re -i video.mp4 -re -i audio.mp3 -map 0 -map 1:a -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -vf "scale=1024:-2,format=yuv420p" -b:v 2000k -bufsize 3000k -maxrate 2000k -g 60 -b:a 192k -ar 44100 -shortest -f tee "[select=\'v:0,a:0\':f=flv]rtmp://my_ip/normal|[select=\'v:0,a:1\':f=flv]rtmp://my_ip/altaudio|[select=\'a:0\':f=flv:onfail=ignore]rtmp://my_ip/onlyaudio"
```

Comment: it is not working. need to create audio loop also that get place of audio of the video

Comment: @AntonioGargiulo Add `-stream_loop -1` input option before `-i audio.mp3`

Comment: -stream_loop -1        is streamed forever I tried...

Comment: @AntonioGargiulo You didn't specify how many times you wanted it to loop, so I guessed you wanted -1 for non-stop loop.

Comment: i would like that stop at same when finish video....

Comment: @AntonioGargiulo Need `-shortest`. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

ok find solution

```
ffmpeg -re -i /usr/VIDEO/my_video.mp4 -re -i /usr/VIDEO/xaudio.mp3 \
-map 0 -c:v libx264 -vf format=yuv420p -b:v 2000k -bufsize 3000k -maxrate 2000k -s 1024X576 -g 60 -c:a aac -b:a 192k -ar 44100 -f flv rtmp://my_ip/live/pass \
-map 0:v -c:v libx264 -vf format=yuv420p -b:v 2000k -bufsize 3000k -maxrate 2000k -s 1024X576 -g 60 -map 1:a -c:a aac -b:a 192k -ar 44100 -f flv rtmp://my_ip/noaudio/pass \
-map 0:a -c:a aac -b:a 192k -ar 44100 -f flv rtmp://my_ip/onlyaudio/pass
```

and like that gonna work

for looping the audio add `-stream_loop (--NUMBER--)` before the audio where (--NUMBER--)   sis the times that should repeat

once `-stream_loop 1`

twice 1nce `-stream_loop 2`

3 times 1nce `-stream_loop 3`

... and so on

```
ffmpeg -re -i /usr/VIDEO/my_video.mp4 -stream_loop (--NUMBER--) -re -i /usr/VIDEO/xaudio.mp3 \
-map 0 -c:v libx264 -vf format=yuv420p -b:v 2000k -bufsize 3000k -maxrate 2000k -s 1024X576 -g 60 -c:a aac -b:a 192k -ar 44100 -f flv rtmp://my_ip/live/pass \
-map 0:v -c:v libx264 -vf format=yuv420p -b:v 2000k -bufsize 3000k -maxrate 2000k -s 1024X576 -g 60 -map 1:a -c:a aac -b:a 192k -ar 44100 -f flv rtmp://my_ip/noaudio/pass \
-map 0:a -c:a aac -b:a 192k -ar 44100 -f flv rtmp://my_ip/onlyaudio/pass
```

Comment: Wasteful and inefficient because you're encoding the video twice, but I guess my answer was too complicated.

Comment: i was doing encoding just once, but was not working... i don't know why.... and I have done your solution and is not working ... Don't know why :)